# Preferred way to resolve package root in Python

Tags: python, organization, project-organization

I am aware of the following way to determine the directory in which a module is executing:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now let's say I have a package with some modules that need to read a text file located in a subdirectory. Something like this:

```
|-- package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module1.py
|   |-- subdirectory1
|   |   |-- module2.py
|   |-- subdirectory2
|   |   |-- file.txt
```

Let's also say I don't want to use relative paths to the file. My intuition is that it would be best to have a global variable defined somewhere in the package root that gives the absolute path to the package (e.g. the above line of code) and which could be imported by different modules whenever they needed to reference a file inside the package. But where would this variable go? In its own module? Or is it just better for each module to grab its own absolute path, get the package root from that, then append on the location of the file?

Edit: another idea is to store this in `os.environ` and have the modules get it from there. Maybe put the following line in the top level `__init__.py`:

```
os.environ['MY_PACKAGE_ROOT'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the path of the package:

```
os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
```

or if the package is imported itself:

```
os.path.dirname(sys.modules['package']).__file__
```

I have not worked with namespace packages and thier corresponding path themselves.

At times I wish when people ask about "path" stuff in Python I wish they would delineate between a Python module path  "package.subpackage.module" verse a filename path of the operating system ".\package\subdirectory\module.py"

You can also look at Python's documents when the _ *path* _ attribute is set.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the import system. `subdirectory1` and `subdirectory2` should be packages as well (you can make them so by adding an `__init__.py` file to them, and then you can use use Python's normal import mechanism to reference modules:

```
import package.module1
import package.subdirectory1.module2
import package.subdirectory2.file
```

and so forth.

Comment: It was not clear in my original post that the file is not a module--it's some other kind of file like a text file, so this solution won't work. Question is edited to reflect this.

Comment: you can still use the `import` system to do this. create a python file in subdirectory2 that returns a filename or filepointer to the file in its current directory, eg: `from package.subdirectory.file import filename` and in `subdirectory2/file.py`: `filename = os.path.abspath("file.txt")`

Comment: Be aware that importing a subdirectory which does not have an _ _init_ _.py becomes a namespace package which has effects on path information.